# Nodejs Insert and update db when concurrent http request

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a http server (Nodejs). When a request comes , i get data and insert to db (mongdodb) (if already have , i update it) . But problem is when server get concurrent request, mongodb will be inserted more records instead of updating existed record. Any solution ?

Comment: Could you show the code you're using to do the "update" and "insert"... looks like you're not doing any update at all.

Answer (score 0):

The generic way of handling this is by using "upsert". As long as you have a user defined ID (ie, not generated by the driver), "upsert" will insert the document if it doesn't exist, and *update* the document if it already does exist with the supplied ID.

In the following example, the first line will insert the document, and the second line (which is the same) it will update:

```
db.test.update( 
    { _id: "my-own-id" }, 
    { $set: { name: "D", surname: "R", time: "11:34:27.1222" } } ,
    { upsert: true }
);
```

The first time round, this will insert the document:

```
{
    _id: "my-own-id",
    name: "D",
    surname: "R",
    time: "11:34:27.1222"
}
```

Now when it runs again a split second later, the document already does exist, and hence it just gets updated:

```
db.test.update( 
    { _id: "my-own-id" }, 
    { $set: { name: "D", surname: "R", time: "11:34:27.1223" } } ,
    { upsert: true }
);
```

And now, because the document already exists, it is just updated:

```
{
    _id: "my-own-id",
    name: "D",
    surname: "R",
    time: "11:34:27.1223"
}
```

Comment: I think it looks like insert then update. But when requests is concurrent, Is it fast enough to excute ?
Example :

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks like insert then update. But when requests is concurrent, Is it fast enough to excute ?
Example :
first
    {
     _id: "id"
     arr: [1]
    }
then 2 concurrent request come and update arr
    {
     arr: [1,2]   //append 2 to original arr
    }
    {
     arr: [1,3]   //append 3
    }
Will it be [1,2,3] or [..]? because request is concurrent , is command fast enough to update ?